# Аналог команды в MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Переношу базу с `mysql` на `ms sql`.
В `mysql` Встречается в процедурах такая конструкция:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finish_cycle = TRUE;
OPEN cur;
SET finish_cycle = FALSE;
WHILE finish_cycle = FALSE DO
    -- какие то операции
  FETCH cur
END WHILE;
CLOSE cur;
```

Переношу так:

```
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN 
       -- какие то операции
       FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    END
    CLOSE cur_client_sessions
```

А как обработчик ошибок преобразовать с `mysql` на `ms sql` не могу понять? И нужна ли она вообще? Или как ёё использовать с try/catch?

Comment: TRY...CATCH + THROW

Comment: @NickProskuryakov А есть ли смысл обрабатывать? Такая ошибка(HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND) в ms sql есть?